# Does logistical regression is the better method for creating a Scoring Model?

Tags: python, dataset, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I have a data-set of user details, in which I want to generate a score for each user.

The needed output range looks like low, medium and high.I am working on logistical regression.

Is that the right approach to handle these types of problems?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: It is decent - in most cases suggested - model to start with.

The more important question, that in my opinion, you should be asking here is what KIND of user data you have and HOW does it perform against the model of choice:

```
  - data has a large number of features: you probably want to run a PCA, XGBOOST or another feature importance evaluation to separate useful features from noise features
  - you have a large amount of text data, i.e. logs: you might want to attach a naive Bayes, tf/idf or another model that performs well with text-based data
  - does your data tend to overfit when using model X? Maybe you want to do data engineering or try a different model
```

My suggestion to you is to first build the LR model and see how it performs on your train/test/predict datasets and evaluate whether the performance is acceptable for your needs and only then think/discuss about different models/approaches.

Comment: Sure, I will work with an LR model and after analyzing the output, will get back to you. thanks